# Организация распределения прав доступа.

Tags: проектирование, java

Добрый день!

Пишу на java сравнительно недолго, скоро будет год.  Начал делать билинг с функционалом который нужно строго разделять по привилегиям доступа.

До сего момента делал я так - у каждого пользователя есть своя группа, которая выражается целым числом, начальные права от 1 до 10, администраторы от 11 до 20, супер пользователь 21 - 30. Столкнулся с проблемой - что такая система очень плоская, не гибкая и с увеличением функционала все сложнее давать нужным пользователям(некоторые функции необходимо дать разным группам и тп.)

На данный момент склоняюсь к схеме когда каждой функциональной единице будет присвоен свой код и в БД будет таблица в которой будет прописано что к данной функции пользователь будет иметь доступ или наоборот, доступ будет запрещен. В приложении создать один статик класс в котором будут хранится все правила для данного пользователя и соответственно будут гетеры. - Данная система получается очень гибкой, но уж больно громоздкой.

Поделитесь пожалуйста своими решениями организации доступа к различным частям программы для различных пользователей.

Answer (score 3):

Почти все так.

Единственное, что я ярый поклонник двух вещей:

- права это не числовой код - это "ТЕГ", строка - CAN_CHANGE_PASS, CAN_EDIT_DOCS, CAN_DELETE_FILE - с точки зрения конечного потребления ресурсов - разница не слишком велика, но гораздо удобнее - если при написании прав и программы курить одно и тоже, то можно даже не записывать.
- структура группа+индивидуальные права. Есть группы прав доступа, в зависимости от выполняемых функций. Для избранных можно добавить что-то руками.

При запросе прав, сначала идет проверка, что разрешено группам, в которые входит пользователь, потом корректируется индивидуальными параметрами - вот этот общий список и отдается клиенту (а лучше хранится и проверяется сервером).

Comment: С группами хорошая идея. Создам четыре таблицы - groups,gruop_rule,individual_rule.
В group - будут храниться группы с названиями и описаниями. В них будут всевозможные настройки прав. Каждый пользователь будет принадлежать своей группе и на пользователя будет распространятся права из group_rule, права из individual_rule будут приписываться(если они есть) по верх group_rule.

Comment: Это только три таблицы, а еще будет таблица в которою я буду складывать названия действий на которые надо будет настраивать права. По большей части это будут отдельные окна - с этим просто, есть права рисуем окно, если нет посылаем абонента куда подальше.

было еще пару вопросов, но пока их записывал ответ сам собой пришел. Спасибо огромное за помощь, Ваш ответ позволил мне взглянуть на проблему с другой стороны. Давно у меня озарений не было )))

Comment: Только смотрите, чтобы проверка прав (с поиском по базе) не занимала слишком много времени.

Comment: по базе я и не буду проверять, при логине буду получать все правила для данного пользователя в статик класс, в нем будут метод который будет возвращать какие права он имеет на действие которое буду передавать в метод.
Тут самое объемное это база данных с нужными правилами. По такому же принципу сделаю настройки оператора, что бы хранились в БД, и при логине они появлялись.